# stop php loop with html button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is it possible to stop the PHP loop with a button that appears in my js page?
Here the post request:

```
$("#startLoop").click(function () {
  var postData = {
    'data': "some data",
  };
  $.post("http://mySite/?controller=myController&action=startLoop", postData)
    .done(function (data) {
    });
});
```

my php code:

```
public function startLoop()
{

    $ArrayObj = getDataFromDB();
        foreach($ArrayObj as Obj)
        {
            sleep(1);
            echo "row<br>";
        }
}
```

After that, I need to stop php loop with html button.Is it possible?

Comment: You can't interact with PHP like that.

Comment: You could make a loop in JS and fetch each data piece then have the HTML stop the JS. It isn't possible to interact client side with PHP though (aside from AJAX).

Comment: i wrote just simple loop, my question is if it possible to stop it?

Comment: You can break out of a loop by putting http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php in your loop.

Comment: @AuditeMarlow not like the OP wants. OP wants the client side action to kill the PHP execution.

Comment: @igorb0214 No, not in the way you are going. You'll need to use ajax and modify the PHP.

Comment: `public function stopLoop()
{
$_SESSION["stop"] = 'true';
}`
and in the loop add condition like this: 
`if($_SESSION["stop"] == 'true') break;`

maybe something like this?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for the client (browser) to interact with what's going on behind the screens on the server (PHP).

Comment: better to add more details about it, OP might not have any info about it. seems to me like this.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer.
No it is not possible

Long answer
PHP is server site, JS is client side. they are not really connected. AJAX just opens a php page ande returns the value. but it could be any page.

Comment: You can add more to your answer to make it better.

Comment: I thought, just keep it short but I added some more info

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't necessarily want PHP to be running any would-be endless loops in a single script awaiting outside interruption; I'd suggest you use something like Node.js for an operation like that - along side the socket.io package you could do this exactly, just in javascript.